# Mongo Authentication

Tags: mongodb

I have set up two servers s1 and s2. s1 is the server that a web server is running on while s2 is the server that my mongodb is running on. I have set up authentication on the mongo instance for security. When I try to connect to the mongo instance on s2 from s1 i get errors when trying to authenticate.

If I use:

```
mongo DB --host HOST --port PORT -u USER -p PASSWORD 
--authenticationDatabase DB --authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-1
```

I get this error:

```
Error: 2 SASL authentication support not compiled into client library.
at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228
exception: login failed
```

If I use:

```
mongo DB --host HOST --port PORT -u USER -p PASSWORD 
--authenticationDatabase DB
```

I get this error:

```
Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "Challenge-response authentication using 
getnonce and authenticate commands is disabled.", code: 2 } at 
src/mongo/shell/db.js:228
exception: login failed
```

If I use:

```
mongo DB --host HOST --port PORT
```

I get in but then I need to use db.auth in order to do anything and then I get this error:

```
Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "Challenge-response authentication using 
getnonce and authenticate commands is disabled.", code: 2 }
```

I have no idea why I can't get in. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Which mongo server version are you using?  3.0.X I assume? Then SCRAM-SHA-1 is active by default and your client needs to support it too.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is to do with wrong version of mongo client.
check the version using the command

```
mongo --version
```

I have had problems while logging into mogodb on [https://mlab.com/](https://mlab.com)

The following fixed my problem and I am on Ubuntu xenial

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 0):

- Have you tried specifying the port and the database followed by the host?
  Try: mongo host:port/bbdd -u XXX -p
- Have you enabled TLS / SSL?
- Maybe Mongo is configured to only accept connections from localhost?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From this error:

```
Error: 2 SASL authentication support not compiled into client library.
```

Which also fits the other errors, I think that your client library is incompatible. Compare the versions, upgrade if needed.